# How to convert BigInteger value to Hex in Java

Tags: java, hex, biginteger

I am making a Java program. I have a BigInteger number and I need to convert it to Hexadecimal. I tried the following code:

```
String dec = null;
System.out.println("Enter the value in Dec: ");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
dec = br.readLine();  
BigInteger toHex=new BigInteger(dec,16);
String s=toHex.toString(16);
System.out.println("The value in Hex is: "+ s);
```

However, this does not give me the correct value after conversion. I am not sure how I can achieve the desired output.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What is the value you get? What value did you expect?

Comment: I expect the output contains letters. But the output comes always as numbers.

Comment: What decimal value are you trying with?

Comment: Ex: If I input 15, I expect F. But I get 21.

Comment: `0x15 = 21`. You parsed the input *as* a hex string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should change

```
BigInteger toHex=new BigInteger(dec,16);
```

to

```
BigInteger toHex=new BigInteger(dec,10);
                                     ^
```

Currently you ask the user for a dec-value, and then interpret the input as a hex-value. (That's why the output is identical to the input.)

Comment: need to improve my typing speed

Comment: Ok. But what is the difference between writing: `String s=toHex.toString(16);` and `String s=toHex.toString();` ??

Comment: `toString()` will return a base-10 representation of the number, while `toString(16)` will return a base-16 representation of the number.

Comment: What should I use because both of them gives me the correct output. So I don't understand. If I entered input 15, I get f in both ways.

Answer (score 10):

```
String hexValue = "FFF";
    System.out.println("HexaDecimal Value :"+hexValue);
    BigInteger bigint = new BigInteger(hexValue ,16);
    System.out.println("Big Int Value :"+bigint);
    BigInteger s = new BigInteger("4");
    bigint = bigint.add(s);
    System.out.println("After Addition :"+bigint);
    String hexNewValue = bigint.toString(16);
    System.out.println("HexaDecimal Value after Addition :"+hexNewValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I see the problem:

```
BigInteger toHex=new BigInteger(dec,16);
```

You are converting the number you type to an integer using base 16. Try using `10` here.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
 BigInteger toHex=new BigInteger(dec,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a same questions:
i have a BigInteger value like this:

```
 BigDecimal price = BigDecimal.valueOf(1151234).movePointRight(16);
```

and i want convert price to hex, i just write this code. then it output as i expect:

```
    System.out.println("0x" + price.toBigInteger().toString(16));
    //expect 0x27015cfcb0230820000
    //output 0x27015cfcb0230820000
```