# Convert a large number to hex in Java

Tags: java, hex, decimal, converters

As we know a Max of long is 9223372036854775807

in my case I want to convert this number `dec = 11265437495266153437`  to hex using this method `Integer.toHexString(dec)`

any idea to how get this reasult `res = 9C56DFB710B493DD` !

Comment: Maybe this will help.https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/ OR 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918123/how-to-convert-biginteger-value-to-hex-in-java

Comment: Use `new BigInteger("11265437495266153437").toString(16)`.

Comment: it's solved , thank you all !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `BigInteger::toString( radix )`

Call [`BigInteger::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString(int)) and pass `16` to get hexadecimal text.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = 
                new BigInteger("11265437495266153437", 10)
                .toString(16)
                .toUpperCase()
        ;
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
9C56DFB710B493DD
```

Note that the default radix is `10` so you can skip it and use `new BigInteger("11265437495266153437")` instead which is without any radix parameter.